# How to disable OTP prompt while login keycloak

Tags: keycloak

We have a keycloak cluster in which by mistake the 2-step auth (password with OTP) has been enabled. Now we are not able to login to the keycloak. Is there any way from the backend to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Created an admin user from CLI command using add-user script.
Post that login with new user and disable the OTP functionality.